# Filter properties and format values if they are currency

Tags: typescript, lodash.js

The function I've written in Typescript works great, but I'm not convinced that it's the cleanest and most efficient function.

The function takes an object, omits properties found in an array, and does a check to see if any of the objects properties is in an array called `currencyFields`. It then returns both a map of the properties, and sorted array of objects, where each object is both a key and value.

This formatted and filtered data then gets displayed in an angular5 template, where I iterate over the array, and use the map to display a quick profile of the person. Because angular's `*ngFor` doesn't have a nice way of iterating over an object without writing some custom functionality, I decided to just return both an object and array that I could use.

Questions:

I like using lodash's functional programming approach, but I'm having a hard time factoring-out the `if` statement from the `reduce` function. It'd be cool to writing something like `_.chain(properties).omit().reduce()....`. Is that possible? Maybe I'm getting too hung-up on the "look" of the code.

For the `properties` argument, it is currently an `object` type, but was an `Interface`. I removed the interface because any number of properties based on if they are in the `showPropertiesOnlyIfDataExists` array, could be removed and I didn't want to make each interface property optional, so instead, I went with a default object type. Am I thinking about this correctly?

```
export interface IPropDetails {
    showNo1: string;
    showNo2: string;
    name: string;
    address: string;
    city: string;
    state: string;
    country: string;
    salary: string;
    bonus: string;
    manager: boolean;
}


// using a config file where these are defined so just stubbing these here for now
const showPropertiesOnlyIfDataExists: string[] = ['showNo1', 'showNo2'];
const currencyFields: string[] = ['salary', 'bonus'];

const formatValuesAndFilterProperties = (properties: object): {map: object, list: object[]} => {

    const filteredProps: {} = _.omit(properties, showPropertiesOnlyIfDataExists);

    const filteredPropsAndFormatCurrencyValues: {} = _.reduce(filteredProps, (acc, value, key) => {
        if (currencyFields.includes(key) && _.isNumber(value)) {
            value = this.convertPropertyValueToCurrency(value);
        }

        acc[key] = value;
        return acc;
    }, {});

    return {
        map: filteredPropsAndFormatCurrencyValues,
        list: _.sortBy(_.map(filteredPropsAndFormatCurrencyValues, (value, key) => ({key: key, value: value})), o => o.key)
    };

}


const exampleData: object = {
    showNo1: '',
    showNo2: 'show no 2',
    name: 'Jim Smit',
    address: '123 elm',
    city: 'portland',
    state: 'OR',
    country: 'USA',
    salary: '100000',
    bonus: '40000',
    manager: true
};

formatValuesAndFilterProperties(exampleData);
```